# Arrange QDockWidgets in QMainWindow in multiple columns

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout, qdockwidget

I have a class which inherits from [`QMainWindow`](http://images.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/mainwindow-docks-example.png&imgrefurl=http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/mainwindow.html&h=242&w=356&tbnid=yFZtwBCLMXaFaM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=132&docid=6Mw_SKTxQJQy4M&client=firefox-b-ab&usg=__Y-KePL0VXOD68qOyq14t9iS0lH8=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW9IqjpoHNAhWGOxoKHfNJA18Q9QEIUzAI). In the constructor, I set the `Central Widget` to `NULL` and then add several [`QDockWidgets`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html) to make a user interface which consits of `QDockWidgets` only:

```
UserWidget::UserWidget(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setCentralWidget(NULL);
    // create Widgets for User communication e.g. PushButtons etc.
    // ...
    dockWidget_ = new QDockWidget;
    dockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas);
    dockWidget->setWidget(userWidget_);
    this->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
```

Now I add another QDockWidget but instead of `Qt::RightDockWidgetArea`, I choose `Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea`:

```
    dockWidget_ = new QDockWidget;
    dockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas);
    dockWidget->setWidget(userWidget2_);
    this->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
```

Up to here, the appearance of my program is similar to this:

[image]

Proceeding further with adding another `QDockWidget`:

```
    dockWidget_ = new QDockWidget;
    dockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas);
    dockWidget->setWidget(userWidget3_);
    this->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea /* or Qt::RightDockWidgetArea*/);
```

I end up with one of the area splitted in the middle  :

[image]

But I want to split the layout into 3 columns, similar to:

[image]

However, I did not find any suitable way to do this. Setting the area to `Qt::TopDockWidgetArea` or `Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea` neither provides the desired behavior. I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to use the function [splitDockWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#splitDockWidget) :

```
void QMainWindow::splitDockWidget(QDockWidget *first, QDockWidget *second, Qt::Orientation orientation)
```

In your case, you can put one `QDockWidget` (let's call him `dock1`) on the left and the other two on the right (`dock2` and `dock3`) and the call the function like this :

```
splitDockWidget(dock2, dock3, Qt::Horizontal);
```